SVG not displaying on safari
I exported my image from Figma as an SVG, it combines 11 other images to make this collage. It does not render on Safari. Neither on my MacBook nor my iPhone but renders on Chrome fine. What is wrong? Here is the original file after exporting from Figma:

And here's the SVG code and some of the image encoding included:


<svg width="1440" height="1107" viewBox="0 0 1440 1107" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g clip-path="url(#clip0_1330_2263)">
    <g style="mix-blend-mode:plus-darker">
      <rect x="235.569" y="450.289" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 235.569 450.289)" fill="url(#pattern0_1330_2263)" />
      <rect x="235.569" y="450.289" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 235.569 450.289)" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </g>
    <g style="mix-blend-mode:plus-darker">
      <rect x="1178.27" y="-93.979" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 1178.27 -93.979)" fill="url(#pattern1_1330_2263)" />
      <rect x="1178.27" y="-93.979" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 1178.27 -93.979)" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </g>
    <g style="mix-blend-mode:plus-darker">
      <rect x="-340.128" y="541.688" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 -340.128 541.688)" fill="url(#pattern2_1330_2263)" />
      <rect x="-340.128" y="541.688" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 -340.128 541.688)" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </g>
    <g style="mix-blend-mode:plus-darker">
      <rect x="602.572" y="-2.58044" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 602.572 -2.58044)" fill="url(#pattern3_1330_2263)" />
      <rect x="602.572" y="-2.58044" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 602.572 -2.58044)" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </g>
    <g style="mix-blend-mode:plus-darker">
      <rect x="511.261" y="927.801" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 511.261 927.801)" fill="url(#pattern4_1330_2263)" />
      <rect x="511.261" y="927.801" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 511.261 927.801)" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </g>
    <g style="mix-blend-mode:plus-darker">
      <rect x="-64.4355" y="1019.2" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 -64.4355 1019.2)" fill="url(#pattern5_1330_2263)" />
      <rect x="-64.4355" y="1019.2" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 -64.4355 1019.2)" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </g>
    <g style="mix-blend-mode:plus-darker">
      <rect x="878.264" y="474.931" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 878.264 474.931)" fill="url(#pattern6_1330_2263)" />
      <rect x="878.264" y="474.931" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 878.264 474.931)" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </g>
    <g style="mix-blend-mode:plus-darker">
      <rect x="1153.96" y="952.443" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 1153.96 952.443)" fill="url(#pattern7_1330_2263)" />
      <rect x="1153.96" y="952.443" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 1153.96 952.443)" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </g>
    <g style="mix-blend-mode:plus-darker">
      <rect x="-40.1211" y="-27.2223" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 -40.1211 -27.2223)" fill="url(#pattern8_1330_2263)" />
      <rect x="-40.1211" y="-27.2223" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 -40.1211 -27.2223)" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </g>
    <g style="mix-blend-mode:plus-darker">
      <rect x="-615.819" y="64.1766" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 -615.819 64.1766)" fill="url(#pattern9_1330_2263)" />
      <rect x="-615.819" y="64.1766" width="514.624" height="514.624" transform="rotate(-30 -615.819 64.1766)" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </g>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern0_1330_2263" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlink:href="#image0_1330_2263" transform="translate(-0.43633) scale(0.000749064)" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="pattern1_1330_2263" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlink:href="#image1_1330_2263" transform="translate(-0.2494) scale(0.00059952)" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="pattern2_1330_2263" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlink:href="#image2_1330_2263" transform="translate(-0.248976) scale(0.000585138)" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="pattern3_1330_2263" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlink:href="#image3_1330_2263" transform="translate(0 -0.16625) scale(0.0025)" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="pattern4_1330_2263" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlink:href="#image4_1330_2263" transform="translate(-0.251252) scale(0.000834725)" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="pattern5_1330_2263" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlink:href="#image5_1330_2263" transform="translate(-0.166667) scale(0.000520833)" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="pattern6_1330_2263" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlink:href="#image6_1330_2263" transform="translate(-0.248895) scale(0.000736377)" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="pattern7_1330_2263" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlink:href="#image7_1330_2263" transform="scale(0.00132979)" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="pattern8_1330_2263" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlink:href="#image8_1330_2263" transform="translate(0 -0.16625) scale(0.0025)" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="pattern9_1330_2263" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlink:href="#image9_1330_2263" transform="translate(-0.248663) scale(0.0013369)" />
    </pattern>
    <clipPath id="clip0_1330_2263">
      <rect width="1513" height="1107" fill="white" transform="translate(-6)" />
    </clipPath>
    <image id="image0_1330_2263" width="2500" height="1335" xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEA8ADwAAD/7QCOUGhvdG9zaG9w



This is how I'm rendering the SVG image with Next.JS:
<Image
   className="absolute left-0 top-0 h-full w-full object-cover object-center"
   src="/assets/Hero.svg"
   fill={true}
 />

I've also tried with the  tag and that did not solve the problem.

SVG appears incomplete at a cursory glance. Are you sure you have the complete code?

The rest of the code is just encoded images which are very very long, I mentioned "some of the image encoding included" for this reason.

Provide a complete SVG that fails in Safari, and please slim it down to a minimal SVG. We are not going to do that work for you and go on a wild SVG goose chase.

I would suggest removing the mix-blend-modes and moving the defs section right after the svg opening tag. Safari doesn't support many "newer" css properties on SVG sub elements. And there used to be a bug where Safari couldn't use a def that was defined lower in the document.

@MichaelMullany Removing mix-blend-mode worked, thank you!!

Yes - it was very optimistic of you to think that a property first introduced in 2016 might be working in Safari in 2024.

Not me who did that, Figma generated the svg @MichaelMullany

That was a joke about Safari's terribly slow implementation of new web stuff

This is probably due to Safari's handling of base64-encoded images and of xlink:href.
Replace xlink:href with href in the <use> elements:
<use href="#image0_1330_2263" transform="translate(-0.43633) scale(0.000749064)" />


Please provide an example (e.g. a running snippet) that proves your answer actually solves the WebKit/Safari related rendering problem. Although xlink:href is considered deprecated, it is still supported by all major browsers (mainly because it's still needed by most graphic applications).

Unfortunately, this solution did not work.
